# How to scroll the transcrib of a video in real time in html5

Tags: javascript, html, video

I would like to create a javascript html5 script that allows to have
poster and play a youtube video with its transcript.

and in this script I'd like a button that captures the images from the video as soon as I press the button.

And that the transcript is written in the browser and as the video progresses.

the goal is that at the end of the video I'll have a full article of the video.

Example:

1) I put a youtube link in the script
2) I see in the html5 page the video
3) I press play on the video
4) the transcription how to write in the html page ok
5) at any time I can make a pose of the video to take a screenshot of the image.

the result must be the following.

I'm taking a screenshot so one frame of the video to start with.
I've got the text underneath.
screenshot image 
transcribed text
screenshot image 
transcribed text
screenshot image 
transcribed text
screenshot image 
transcribed text

until the end of the video

the screenshot captures it's me who makes them by pressing the button to capture the screenshot.

I managed to make a page that takes the screenshot with a button from a local mp4 video.
but what I can't do, and that's where I need your help:

1) is to play a youtube video in an html5 page with always the screen shot button
2) write in real time the transcription in a html5 page until the end of the video.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try anything on your own for this cause? *I managed to make a page that takes the screenshot with a button...* Where are the tries can we see it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>

var videoId = 'video';
    var scaleFactor = 0.5;
    var snapshots = [] ;

    /**
     * Captures a image frame from the provided video element.
     *
     * @param {Video} video HTML5 video element from where the image frame will be captured.
     * @param {Number} scaleFactor Factor to scale the canvas element that will be return. This is an optional parameter.
     *
     * @return {Canvas}
     */
    function capture(video, scaleFactor) {
        if (scaleFactor == null) {
            scaleFactor = 1;
        }
        var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
        var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
        innerHTML = "<br>";
        return canvas  ;

    }

    /**
     * Invokes the <code>capture</code> function and attaches the canvas element to the DOM.
     */
    function shoot() {
        var video = document.getElementById(videoId);
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var canvas = capture(video, scaleFactor);
        canvas.onclick = function() {
            window.open(this.toDataURL(image/jpg));
        };
        snapshots.unshift(canvas);
        output.innerHTML = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            output.appendChild(snapshots[i])  ;
        }
    }

(function() {
  var captureit = document.getElementById('cit');
  captureit.click();
})();
</script>

<style>

.wrap {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#output {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 4px;
  position: relative;
  border: dotted 1px #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}

.button {
  border: solid 2px #ccc;
}
</style>


<html>
   <body>





        <div class="wrap">
  <video id="video" width="600" controls="true">
    <source src = "http://127.0.0.1/divi.mp4" type = "video/mp4"></source>
    <!-- FireFox 3.5 -->
    <source src = "http://127.0.0.1/divi.mp4" type = "video/mp4"></source>
    <!-- WebKit -->
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video tag. Please download FireFox 3.5 or higher.
  </video>
  <br/>
  <button id="cit" onclick="shoot()" class="button">Capture</button>
  <br/>
  <div id="output">



  </div>
```

here are two scripts the first one has a button that captures the images of an MP4 video
and the second one that stupidly extracts all the images from a video automatically...

what I'm missing is:

1) put the link of any youtube video that is displayed in the html5 page
2) when I click on play I get the transcript which is written below the video automatically.
3) I want to do a pose to make a screen capture
4) continue transcription 
5) image capture of the video etc...

text
image
text 
image 
until the end of the video
the goal of getting my full article.

I have a lot of tutorials on youtube and I would like to have them in documentation on my website.

create a complete article for each video

the best thing is to have a motion capture of the automatic image.

that is to say:

1) I click on the video
2) the script takes a first capture of the video
3) the transcription is written below the image captured in the html5 page
4) as soon as the image changes the script detects it and takes the print screen by itself without any button.

and so on until the end of the video without my intervention. 
it creates a complete article on its own 
just by putting my youtube link!!
It'll be the best of the best...

thank you for your support I'm sure that among you there are people who have websites and would like to have a script that can do articles alone...
3) as soon as

Comment: if these are your videos why do you need to capture transcriptions? there are services that can help with this if they are longer videos and you don't have a script (eg https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-to-text/#features)